# Creating a list with >255 elements

Tags: python, list, parameters, syntax-error, literals

Ok, so I'm writing some python code (I don't write python much, I'm more used to java and C).

Anyway, so I have collection of integer literals I need to store.
(Ideally >10,000 of them, currently I've only got 1000 of them)
I would have liked to be accessing the literals by file IO, or by accessing there source API, but that is disallowed.
And not ontopic anyway.

So I have the literals put into a list:

```
    src=list(0,1,2,2,2,0,1,2,... ,2,1,2,1,1,0,2,1)
#some code that uses the src
```

But when I try to run the file it comes up with an error because there are more than 255 arguments.
So the constructor is the problem.
How should I do this?

The data is intitally avaiable to me as a space deliminated textfile.
I just searched and replaced and copied it in

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use `[]` instead of `list()`, you won't run into the limit because `[]` is not a function.

```
src = [0,1,2,2,2,0,1,2,... ,2,1,2,1,1,0,2,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src = [int(value) for value in open('mycsv.csv').read().split(',') if value.strip()]
```

Or are you not able to save text file in your system?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any file IO.